# Leer fichero JS sin actualizar toda la web

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy haciendo un botón que me cambia en una web el nombre de un fichero js dentro de un <script que está en el head, lo he conseguido y se me va cambiando. Lo malo es que no sé como hacer que lea el fichero nuevo y que refresque los datos que tengo a lo largo de la página. 
Consigo que la línea:
`<script id="datoslee" src="datos.js"></script>`
me cambie a 
`<script id="datoslee" src="datos2.js"></script>`
Pero no sé como hacer para que se refresque todo lo que depende de este fichero en la página. Es necesario quedarnos el campo "id".

Se agradecería ayuda
Un saludo y gracias
M

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás cambiando el src pero no estás recargando el elemento para que lo pida y ejecute, con recrearlo y volver a añadirlo debería funcionar.

```
var mijs=document.getElementById("datoslee");
var padre=mijs.parentNode;
// No hace falta quitar el antiguo
//padre.removeChild(mijs);

var mijs=document.createElement("script");
mijs.setAttribute("src", "example2.js");
padre.appendChild(mijs);
```

Si quieres impedir que el antiguo se ejecute una primera vez símplemente no lo añadas

Comment: Ante todo, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Buenas Edoldin, veo que sí que lo quita y lo pone .... pero no lee el js. Al principo de los js que cambio tengo un console.log que no los hace ..... o sé si estoy haciendo algo mal. Decir eso sí que si pones los console.log despues del remove y otro despues de append, en ambos consoles sale como si no se hubiese quitado mijs

Comment: Buenos días Manuel, corrijo la respuesta, no hay que reañadirlo únicamente, hay que recrearlo para que el navegador entienda que tiene que cargarlo pero en este caso se estarían ejecutando ambos, no estás quitando la ejecución del primero.